# Josh Smith's legendary article: I need a bit more on the DataBinding that takes place

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, msdn

It’s about [*the MSDN article of Josh Smith on MVVM*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and the sample application. I know there are lots of question on SO about this topic, and I’ve explored them all. Most of them are focused on MVVM, but my issue is, I think, more XAML related than MVVM.

The sample application contains the following XAML for the Workspaces area -

```
<Border Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource MainBorderStyle}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=WorkspacesTemplate}"/>
</Border>
```

and the related resources are -

```
//Explains how to render the 'Workspace' content area in the main window
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
    <TabControl Margin="4" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"                    
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ClosableTabItemTemplate}"/>
</DataTemplate>

//Explains how to render a tab item with a close button
<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemTemplate">
    <DockPanel Width="120">
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}" Content="X" Cursor="Hand" 
                DockPanel.Dock="Right" Focusable="False" FontFamily="Courier" 
                FontSize="9" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,1,0,0" Padding="0" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Width="16" Height="16"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I still don't understand -

- The syntax `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` should bind the ItemsSource directly to the TabControl’s DataContext, rather than to any of the DataContext’s properties. But where exactly is the TabControl’s DataContext being set?
- How exactly is `Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}"` creating a binding between ItemsSource of the TabControl and the Workspaces (the ObservableCollection of WorkspaceViewModel)?
- The article says *By relying on data binding, the `Content` property of a `TabItem` receives a ViewModelBase-derived object to display*. How ?!? Ok, through *data binding*. But that is just too much to abstract away, for me.

In general I’m missing `the way binding is flowing/working through these two resources behind the scene` to load the Views in the TabItems. To me it's like, *what is causing what to be bound to what*.

This legendary article and the sample application is something extremely useful for WPF/MVVM beginners. But it’s not much elaborative. I myself have learned using MVVM with this one. I think there *is* and *will be* some others like me. So, can anyone explain the binding sequences a little bit more elaborately please?

**Relevant Note :**

May be it'll give you a hint of what I already know in this context, and help you in answering. I'm a beginner level WPF application developer. With my *not so good* knowledge on XAML -

- I’m aware of the magic through typed-`DataTemplate` of displaying the View when the ViewModel type occurs, and then setting the ViewModel as the DataContext of that View
- My understanding is, Content tells *what* to display on a ContentControl and ContentTemplate tells *how* to display that Content.
- I have a little more than basic data binding concept, and I've worked in some WPF/MVVM projects.

Comment: try Snoop(http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com) and explore the world of binding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The syntax ItemsSource="{Binding}" should bind the ItemsSource
>   directly to the TabControl’s DataContext, rather than to any of the
>   DataContext’s properties. But where exactly is the TabControl’s
>   DataContext being set?

By virtue of being a data template, the `TabControl` will have its `DataContext` set (by WPF) to the data item it is templating. In fact, the root-level item in the data template will have its `DataContext` set by WPF. In this case, it's a `TabControl`.

Since the data template is assigned to the `ContentControl`'s `ContentTemplate` property, it will automatically receive the `ContentControl`'s `Content` as its `DataContext`.

> How exactly is Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" creating a binding
>   between ItemsSource of the TabControl and the Workspaces (the
>   ObservableCollection of WorkspaceViewModel)?

I think my previous answer addresses this, but let me re-state it in a form that directly answers this question. The binding on the `ContentControl` ensures that the `DataContext` for the `DataTemplate` is set to the workspace collection. Thus, the `TabControl` can bind to the workspace collection by specifying a `Binding` without a `Path`.

> The article says By relying on data binding, the Content property of a
>   TabItem receives a ViewModelBase-derived object to display. How ?!?
>   Ok, through data binding. But that is just too much to abstract away,
>   for me.

Again, this comes down to WPF automatically assigning the correct object as the data context of the generated item (a `TabItem` in this case). When an `ItemsControl` (such as `TabControl`) is bound to a collection, it generates a container (a `TabItem` in this case) for each item in the bound collection. The container automatically receives the data item (a workspace view model in this case) as its data context.

Comment: Thanks Kent, that was a great answer. I think `it will automatically receive the ContentControl's Content as its DataContext` made things a lot clear. ItemsControl's generating containers and the container's automatically receiving data context was something i had no idea of. Where can I find such technical details documented? And how do I know when it comes down to WPF automatically assigning the correct object as the data context of the generated item? Josh Smith's a Guru, and I'm *not*. I need to get them from somewhere, right?

Comment: The API docs for ItemsControl do a half-decent job of explaining the item container generation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx

Answer (score 0):

"But where exactly is the TabControl’s DataContext being set?" Workspaces is the DataContext and so the Itemssource for the TabControl.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=WorkspacesTemplate}"/>
```

"How exactly is Content="{Binding Path=Workspaces}" creating a binding between ItemsSource of the TabControl and the Workspaces (the ObservableCollection of WorkspaceViewModel)?" Workspaces are the DataContext for the DataTemplate/TabControl and the ItemsSource is set to the DataContext.

```
 <TabControl Margin="4" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```

"The article says By relying on data binding, the Content property of a TabItem receives a ViewModelBase-derived object to display. How ?!?" i dont know the article, but i assume that Workspaces is a collection of object derived from ViewModelBase. every tabitem represent on item from the collection and so a viewmodelbase-derived object.